# Perform select operations in React/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, select

Beginner here.

I would like to understand how to parse the data from "rows" - sql.query parameter.
Please show code snippets to

1. read/parse one row(like in this case)
2. Loop through all the output rows (I want to read each row and push it into a new table)

This entire piece of code goes into a router.route()

```
sqQuery=
  "select request_type_level from Request_Type where request_type_id = "+
  request_type;
  console.log(sqQuery);
  sql.query(connectionString, sqQuery, (err, rows) => {
    if (err != null) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(rows);
      request_level = rows.request_type_level
      res.json("Data successfully added in Request Details Table");
    }
  });
```

Comment: provide pls some details - what is your question? You can start here https://node-postgres.com/

Comment: I want to read a specific column into a variable from "rows" output

Comment: You've to give information about the platform you are using.

Comment: This is javascript express.